# How to find a duplicate in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

**What am I trying to achieve?**

So I have an array which needs to be checked for duplicates and if a duplicate is found I want to display the duplicate found using console.log for now. I must add this this code is based within a function.

The user will then add to this array using some input within the frontend , which is I currently have completed but it is not needed to solve this problem.

Here is my Array below which i want to find if there are duplicates within it.

```
  const repeatedNumEvent = {
      PlayerNumber: this.state.PlayerNumber,
      eventType: this.state.eventType
    };
```

basically if an new array object has identical values then display the duplicate

I assume I will have to use a for loop using the .length function but i am unsure how to achieve my task.

Possible array data below

```
{PlayerNumber: "12", eventType: "Goal"}
```

If you have any question just ask below. Thanks.

Comment: Please post an example of the array data

Comment: This isn't really a react question is it?

Comment: apologies @dwjohnston , just a habit lol

Comment: @Chev I have updated my description for you . this is an example which i have got from using console.log()

Comment: Please, show us a bit of code. I don't see any array, but a simple object with two properties.

Comment: Are you wanting to find duplicates values within an existing array?  Or just check that the value you are trying to add to the existing array is not a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should do the trick. It will loop the array and check if we already have the item already. It will `console.log` as requested, but also leave you with an array of distinct and duplicate items to process as needed

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [
    {PlayerNumber: "13", eventType: "Goal"},
    {PlayerNumber: "13", eventType: "Goal"},
    {PlayerNumber: "12", eventType: "Goal"},
    {PlayerNumber: "12", eventType: "Goal"},
    {PlayerNumber: "14", eventType: "Goal"}
];

let distinct = [];
let duplicates = [];
data.forEach((item, index, object) => {
    if (distinct.find(current => current.PlayerNumber === item.PlayerNumber && current.eventType === item.eventType)) {
        console.info('duplicate found');

        duplicates.push(item);
    } else {
        distinct.push(item);
    }
});

console.info('duplicates:', duplicates);
console.info('distinct:', distinct);
```

Comment: could also use a lodash _.isEqual to compare objects

Comment: For sure, wanted to keep it vanilla this time, but highly recommend [lodash](https://lodash.com/)